# Prevent the 'slide down' effect in Fancybox

Tags: fancybox

By default it looks like there is a slide down effect as you switch from image to image with fancybox.

Is there a way to inhibit that or change it to a different effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the API option `nextMethod: 'fade'` for instance or choose your preferred transition method

Comment: Thanks for that. I had assumed fade was the default but it doesnt seem to be

Answer (score 2):

You just change param in nextEffect and prevEffect, we  had 3 opions 'elastic', 'fade' or 'none'.