# How to combine jQuery code for fancybox 2 fadein effect and to use title-id?

Tags: jquery, title, fadein, fancybox-2

I am using fancy box 2.

I have some code that allows me to use data-title-id to give the gallery items in fancybox a title with anchor in them.

I also want to use another piece of code which changes the animation of the fancybox gallery images as they transition to the next or previous images.

My question is how do I combine both these scripts in order for them to function on the same page? Both are below.

```
 $(".fancybox")
    .fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function () {
        var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');

        if (id) {
            el = $('#' + id);

            if (el.length) {
                this.title = el.html();
            }
        }
    }
});


(function ($, F) {
    F.transitions.resizeIn = function () {
        var previous = F.previous,
            current = F.current,
            startPos = previous.wrap.stop(true).position(),
            endPos = $.extend({
                opacity: 1
            }, current.pos);

        startPos.width = previous.wrap.width();
        startPos.height = previous.wrap.height();

        previous.wrap.stop(true).trigger('onReset').remove();

        delete endPos.position;

        current.inner.hide();

        current.wrap.css(startPos).animate(endPos, {
            duration: current.nextSpeed,
            easing: current.nextEasing,
            step: F.transitions.step,
            complete: function () {
                F._afterZoomIn();

                current.inner.fadeIn("fast");
            }
        });
    };

}(jQuery, jQuery.fancybox));

$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    nextMethod: 'resizeIn',
    nextSpeed: 250,

    prevMethod: false,

    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you put more code in http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/5EV8r/ ?

Comment: Please see this page as an example http://www.flatness.eu/test.html. If you click on the slideshow I want it to transition differently through the gallery of images, fading in and out rather than sliding sideways. However I need to keep the code that enables the data-title-id to be used to add links in the titles under the images. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind the selector `$(".fancybox")` to fancybox twice but combining all the options from both scripts in a single one like

```
(function ($, F) {
    F.transitions.resizeIn = function () {
        var previous = F.previous,
            current = F.current,
            startPos = previous.wrap.stop(true).position(),
            endPos = $.extend({
                opacity: 1
            }, current.pos);
        startPos.width = previous.wrap.width();
        startPos.height = previous.wrap.height();
        previous.wrap.stop(true).trigger('onReset').remove();
        delete endPos.position;
        current.inner.hide();
        current.wrap.css(startPos).animate(endPos, {
            duration: current.nextSpeed,
            easing: current.nextEasing,
            step: F.transitions.step,
            complete: function () {
                F._afterZoomIn();
                current.inner.fadeIn("fast");
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery, jQuery.fancybox));

$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    nextMethod: 'resizeIn',
    nextSpeed: 250,
    prevMethod: false,
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },
    beforeLoad: function () {
        var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');
        console.log(id);
        if (id) {
            el = $('#' + id);

            if (el.length) {
                this.title = el.html();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ5rC/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');

            if (id) {
                el = $('#' + id);

                if (el.length) {
                    this.title = el.html();
                }
            }         

        },
     openEffect: 'none',
     prevEffect: 'slideUp',
     nextEffect: 'slideDown'
    });



(function ($, F) {
    F.transitions.slideUp = function() {
       F.wrap.slideUp();
    };

    F.transitions.slideDown = function() {
       F.wrap.slideDown();
    };

}(jQuery, jQuery.fancybox));
```

If you want the fade effect as you said, just use:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');

            if (id) {
                el = $('#' + id);

                if (el.length) {
                    this.title = el.html();
                }
            }         

        },
     openEffect: 'fade',
     prevEffect: 'fade',
     nextEffect: 'fade'
    });
```

**Example with Fade effects:** http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/eeXde/

It might help you:
 
[Fancybox, Custom Open Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356669/fancybox-custom-open-transition)
[Prevent the 'slide down' effect in Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843029/prevent-the-slide-down-effect-in-fancybox)